# How to format a FUSE volume?

Tags: linux, formatting, fuse

If I have a FUSE filesystem driver installed (could be for NTFS, ODS-5, unixv7, etc.) and mount a blank file (created with, for example, `dd if=/dev/zero of=blankfile count=2G`), how is it expected to be formatted?

Is there `fuse-mkfs` or `fuse-format` tool?    I looked through the API and there does not appear to be any provision for formatting or initializing a volume.  Maybe FUSE is intended only to access already existing filesystems?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking tbh. What does mkfs has to do with FUSE or the filesystem driver? For example, you need e2fsprogs (mke2fs) to create ext2/3/4 too even when the driver is in kernel.

Comment: Or are you actually asking: how should I mkfs when the target is a file but not a block device?

Comment: @TomYan:  I think the latter.  If I no longer have access to a VAX/VMS system to create a filesystem but want to experiment with such a disk image, can I create and use a legitimate disk image?  A read/write FUSE implementation seems like it has almost everything required except being able to format.  Or does it?

Comment: I think you are looking for `losetup`? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html

Comment: I still don't quite get your  second question, but again the formatting part does have anything to do with FUSE at all. You are probably just confused because project like ntfs-3g includes both a FUSE driver and utilities like mkfs (and many more; e.g. ntfsclone) for the filesystem.

Comment: For example, take a look at the free exFAT implementation here: https://github.com/relan/exfat/releases You can see that the utilites (mkfs et. al.) are seperated from the FUSE driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FUSE is designed to operate on filesystems in userspace  - it says nothing about creating the filesystem representation on a disk the first place - and this would be outside the scope of FUSE - you just use regular utilities.

As it would be a one of, I would expect you would simply use the appropriate mkfs tools (if they exist).  So for NTFS you might use  mkfs.ntfs or mkntfs (depending on distro, version etc) - ie outside of FUSE.

The same would be true of any other filesystem that you could find a way to formaat.

Comment: According to http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/lectures/15-filesys/  the FUSE API handles mknod, unlink, read, write, open, truncate, rmdir, readdir and getattr calls - not block calls.